# RxJava compare different items from two observables (java 7)

Tags: java, rx-java, contains

I have two Observables ob1 & ob2 that emit items . If ob1.item is contained in ob2 I want to ignore it.

Example :

```
ob1 contains A,B,C,D

ob2 contains E,C,B,G,J,O
```

output :

```
ob contains A,D
```

What is the best  way to express this ?

Comment: I know there is a distinct() operator but it do the inverse. :(

Comment: I so much wait for @akarnokd to answer this. I've got a headache because of this, so interesting.

Comment: @akarnokd  can you help me !  I hope u will  read the comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a [contains](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/contains.html) operator which returns `Observable<Boolean>` for whether observable contains given element.

```
Observable<Boolean> contains = observable2.contains(string);
```

What you need is to map all elements from `observable1` to those boolean observables

```
observable1.map(new Func1<String, Observable<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> call(final String string) {
        return observable2.contains(string);
    }
})
```

This would give you `Observable<Observable<Boolean>>`, but it would be hard to work with this. Therefore you concatenate all those boolean observables into one. Luckilly, all you need to do for that is to use `concatMap` instead of `map`

```
observable1.concatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> call(final String string) {
        return observable2.contains(string);
    }
})
```

Now you have an `observable1` that contains your elements and an `Observable<Boolean>` that contains boolean for whether the element in `observable1` is contained in `observable2`

```
observable1:            A ---- B ---- C ---- D
concatMapObservable:    false  true   true   false
```

You can easily `zip` those two observables into an observable which will pass the elements that are not contained in `observable2` and replace others with an empty string

```
[concatMapObservable].zipWith(observable1, new Func2<Boolean, String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(final Boolean contains, final String string) {
        return contains ? "" : string;
    }
}
```

Then you filter the empty strings

```
[zippedObservable].filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(final String string) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(string);
    }
})
```

---

The whole code put together:

```
Observable<String> observable1 = Observable.from(new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D"});
Observable<String> observable2 = Observable.from(new String[]{"E", "C", "B", "G", "J", "O"});

observable1.concatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> call(final String string) {
        return observable2.contains(string);
    }
}).zipWith(observable1, new Func2<Boolean, String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(final Boolean contains, final String string) {
        return contains ? "" : string;
    }
}).filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(final String string) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(string);
    }
}).subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(final String string) {
        Log.d("observable:", string);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The output of your operation cannot be computed until all items of ob2 have been received, as you cannot tell whether an item in ob1 will be contained in ob2 until you know all items that are part of ob2. As a result, you have to wait for ob2 to complete before you can then filter items from ob1.

A possible solution using RxJava2 is below.

```
    Observable<String> ob1 = Observable.fromArray("A", "B", "C", "D");
    Observable<String> ob2 = Observable.fromArray("E", "C", "B", "G", "J", "O");

    Observable.combineLatest(ob2.toList().toObservable(), ob1, (list, value) -> list.contains(value) ? "" : value)
            .filter(value -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(value))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(value -> Log.d("foo", "Value: " + value));
```

Comment: i cant use lambda expressions in java 7 :(

Comment: @mir just replace lambdas with anonymous classes. It is pretty straightforward.